# WooCommerce My Account custom endpoint menu item

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, endpoint

I am working on a project where my account page is a homepage. So what I did I have created a page that holding the shortcode `[woocommerce_my_account]` and made this page homepage from Dashboard->Settings->Reading. Everything works. I have this working endpoints too:

- mydomain.com/orders
- mydomain.com/edit-address

But I am facing trouble when I am making a custom myaccount endpoint. I am doing it in this traditional way:

```
add_action('woocommerce_account_custom-endpoint_endpoint', function(){
    echo 'hello'; 
} );

add_action('init', function() {
    add_rewrite_endpoint('custom-endpoint', EP_ROOT | EP_PAGES); 
});
```

But mydomain.com/custom-endpoint is not pointing to my account page, it is pointing to the index.php or page.php (WordPress template hierarchy).

I am curious to know why it is happening?

Comment: hi. @VincenzoDiGaetano I think this is not similar. I have forgotten to mention if remove my account page from the homepage my custom endpoints are working okay.
I mean mydomain.com/myaccount/custom-endpoint working okay but 
mydomain.com/custom-endpoint not working/

Comment: The `mydomain.com/custom-endpoint` page is not working but it is right. You are using the [**`'woocommerce_account_' . $key . '_endpoint'`**](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-wc-template-functions.html#source-view.3075) hook that adds the content within the WooCommerce "My Account" page.

Comment: mydomain.com is serving the myaccount page, so if add an endpoint with 'woocommerce_account_$key_endpoint', then should not mydomain.com/$key serve that custom endpoint as other default endpoints like mydomain.com/orders are working okay. but it is serving index.php

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Updated:**

**Important:** You need first to declare your home page as the My account page in:
WooCommerce settings > Advanced > My account page field.

Use the following:

```
// Enable endpoint
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_query_vars', 'myaccount_custom_endpoint_query_var' );
function myaccount_custom_endpoint_query_var( $query_vars ) {
    $query_vars['custom-endpoint'] = 'custom-endpoint';

    return $query_vars;
}

// Endpoint displayed content
add_action('woocommerce_account_custom-endpoint_endpoint', 'display_custom_endpoint_content' ); 
function display_custom_endpoint_content(){
    echo '<p>' . __("hello") . '</p>';
}
```

Optionally you can use the following too:

```
// Add it as my account menu item
add_filter ( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'custom_account_menu_items', 10 );
function custom_account_menu_items( $menu_links ){
    $menu_links = array_slice( $menu_links, 0,3 , true )
    + array( 'custom-endpoint' => __('Custom Endpoint') )
    + array_slice( $menu_links, 3, NULL, true );

    return $menu_links;
}

// Endpoint page title
add_filter( 'woocommerce_endpoint_custom-endpoint_title', 'set_my_account_custom_endpoint_title', 10, 2 );
function set_my_account_custom_endpoint_title( $title, $endpoint ) {
    $title = __( "Custom Endpoint", "woocommerce" );

    return $title;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme).

**Edit:** The hook `woocommerce_get_query_vars` is mandatory and replace the function that handle `add_rewrite_endpoint()`, which is not needed anymore *(thanks to @Jitu)*.

You can flush rewrites rules if needed by going to Wordpress settings > Permalinks and "Save changes".

Tested and works.

Comment: Thanks, it is working, when I am using this hook  'woocommerce_get_query_vars'.
Still wondering custom endpoints work okay without this hook when myaccount is not a root url.

Comment: @Jitu Because wooCommerce default endpoints are already defined as query_vars in the core code, So for custom my account endpoints is good to do it, as for example the endpoint title will only be displayed if the query_var is defined.

Comment: Thanks I got my answer. I have another question, 
is  `add_rewrite_endpoint('custom-endpoint', EP_ROOT | EP_PAGES);` is required? 
I can see my custom endpoint works okay without this one when I use 'woocommerce_get_query_vars'.

Comment: sorry I can not agree. I did that, also I am using  `flush_rewrite_rules();` under `init`  hook for testing, it is working okay.

Comment: Also, I have deleted the .htaccess and regenerated it. it is still working.

Comment: I did that, and I can clearly see 

`add_action('woocommerce_account_custom-endpoint_endpoint', function(){
    echo 'Hello';
} );`

`add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_query_vars',function ( $query_vars ) {
    $query_vars['custom-endpoint'] = 'custom-endpoint';
    return $query_vars;
});`
is required things for me. although I will use  `add_rewrite_endpoint ` because all tutorials suggest it. I will investigate more.