# Add custom my account menu item based on user role in WooCommerce 3+

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, endpoint, user-roles

I am using WordPress and WooCommerce and I have followed this article https://rudrastyh.com/woocommerce/my-account-menu.html to add new menu items in WooCommerce my account menus.

This is my working code.

```
function getUserRolesByUserId( $id ) {
    
    if ( !is_user_logged_in() ) { return false; }

    $oUser = get_user_by( 'id', $id );
    $aUser = get_object_vars( $oUser );
    $sRoles = $aUser['roles'];
    return $sRoles;

}

function createMenuBasedonUserRole($userId)
{
    $userRoleIds = getUserRolesByUserId(get_current_user_id());

    $urlMenuData = [];
    if(!empty($userRoleIds) && in_array('mindesk_var_account',$userRoleIds)) {
        
        $urlMenuData = [
            'pageName' => "Clients",
            "pageLink" => "clients"
        ];
        
        
 
    } else if(!empty($userRoleIds) && in_array('mindesk_owner_account',$userRoleIds)) {

        $urlMenuData = [
            'pageName' => "Children",
            "pageLink" => "children"
        ];  
        
    }
    return $urlMenuData;
}

/*
 * Step 1. Add Link (Tab) to My Account menu
 */
add_filter ( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'mindesk_clients_children_link', 40 );

function mindesk_clients_children_link( $menu_links ){
    $urlData = createMenuBasedonUserRole(get_current_user_id());
    
    if(!empty($urlData)){
        $menu_links = array_slice( $menu_links, 0, 5, true ) + array( $urlData['pageLink'] => $urlData['pageName'] ) + array_slice( $menu_links, 5, NULL, true );
    }
    
    return $menu_links;

}

/*
* Step 2. Register Permalink Endpoint
*/
add_action( 'init', 'mindesk_add_menu_endpoint' );
function mindesk_add_menu_endpoint() {  
        
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'clients', EP_PAGES );
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'children', EP_PAGES );
}

/*
* Step 3. Content for the new page in My Account, woocommerce_account_{ENDPOINT NAME}_endpoint
*/
add_action( 'woocommerce_account_clients_endpoint', 'mindesk_clients_my_account_endpoint_content' );
function mindesk_clients_my_account_endpoint_content() {
    require_once(get_template_directory() . '/myaccount/clients.php') ;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_account_children_endpoint', 'mindesk_children_my_account_endpoint_content' );
function mindesk_children_my_account_endpoint_content() {
    require_once(get_template_directory() . '/myaccount/children.php') ;
}
/* Step 4
*/
// Go to Settings > Permalinks and just push "Save Changes" button.
```

And this is my how my new menu called as "Clients" showing.

[image]

As you can see above, I have added new menu and executing the page and based on user role `mindesk_var_account` I need to show `clients` and `mindesk_owner_account` I need to show `children`.

I have created these 2 php pages at `/wp-content/themes/twentytwentyone/myaccount` and its working fine.

However, I want to use `wp_die` or something if user with another role try to access one of the page which they are not allowed to.

So for example if logged in user has `mindesk_var_account` role then if they try to go to  http://localhost/wordpress/my-account/clients/ then i need to use `wp_die()` to not execute it.

I tried to use `wp_die` inside these new 2 pages but then menus and other things executed. I just want something like this.

[image]

I tried to use following code...

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_account_redirect' );
function my_account_redirect() {
    if( is_page( 'my-account' ) ) {
        wp_die('fg');

    }
}
```

But then its checking for all `my-account` pages .. and I want it to be checked only for inner pages like `client` or `children`.

Can someone guide me how can I achieve this what should I do from here on.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are still some little mistakes in your code, some missing things and since WooCommerce 3 there are some related changes within step 2 for My account endpoints. Some things can be simplified too.

To avoid non allowed user roles to access to some prohibited section(s) or endpoint(s) you can use a custom function hooked in `template_redirect` hook that will redirect user to an allowed section.

Here is the complete code:

```
// Custom function that get My account menu item data based on user roles
function get_menu_item_by_user_role() {
    $user_roles = wp_get_current_user()->roles;

    if ( ! empty($user_roles) ) {
        $menu_item = [];

        // if ( in_array('mindesk_var_account', $user_roles) ) {
        if ( in_array( 'mindesk_var_account', $user_roles ) ) {
            $menu_item = [ 'clients' => __( "Clients", "woocommerce" ) ];
        }
        elseif( in_array( 'mindesk_owner_account', $user_roles ) ) {
            $menu_item = [ 'children' => __( "Children", "woocommerce" ) ];
        }
    }
    return $menu_item;
}

// Step 1 - Add Link (Tab) to My Account menu
add_filter ( 'woocommerce_account_menu_items', 'add_mindesk_custom_menu_items', 40 );
function add_mindesk_custom_menu_items( $menu_items ){
    $new_item = get_menu_item_by_user_role();

    if ( ! empty($new_item) ) {
        $menu_items = array_slice( $menu_items, 0, 5, true ) + $new_item + array_slice( $menu_items, 5, null, true );
    }
    return $menu_items;
}

// Step 2 - Enable endpoint (and endpoint permalink) - Since WooCommerce 3
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_query_vars', 'add_mindesk_menu_item_endpoint' );
function add_mindesk_menu_item_endpoint( $query_vars ) {
    $query_vars['clients']  = 'clients';
    $query_vars['children'] = 'children';

    return $query_vars;
}

// Step 3. Content for the new page in My Account, woocommerce_account_{ENDPOINT NAME}_endpoint
add_action( 'woocommerce_account_clients_endpoint', 'add_mindesk_account_clients_endpoint_content' );
function add_mindesk_account_clients_endpoint_content() {
    require_once(get_template_directory() . '/myaccount/clients.php') ;
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_account_children_endpoint', 'add_mindesk_account_children_endpoint_content' );
function add_mindesk_account_children_endpoint_content() {
    require_once(get_template_directory() . '/myaccount/children.php') ;
}

// Step 4. Endpoint page title
add_filter( 'woocommerce_endpoint_clients_title', 'set_mindesk_account_clients_endpoint_title', 10, 2 );
function set_mindesk_account_clients_endpoint_title( $title, $endpoint ) {
    $title = __("Clients", "woocommerce" );

    return $title;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_endpoint_children_title', 'set_mindesk_account_children_endpoint_title', 10, 2 );
function set_mindesk_account_children_endpoint_title( $title, $endpoint ) {
    $title = __( "Children", "woocommerce" );

    return $title;
}

// Step 5. Redirect if not allowed user role
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_mindesk_account_dashboard' );
function redirect_mindesk_account_dashboard() {
    if ( is_account_page() ) {
        global $wp;

        $item_key = array_keys(get_menu_item_by_user_role());
        $page_url = get_permalink( get_option('woocommerce_myaccount_page_id') );

        if ( empty($item_key) &&  ( isset($wp->query_vars['children']) || isset($wp->query_vars['clients']) ) ) {
            wp_safe_redirect( get_permalink($page_id) );
            exit();
        }
        elseif ( 'clients' == reset($item_key) && isset($wp->query_vars['children']) ) {
            wp_safe_redirect( get_permalink($page_id) . 'clients/' );
            exit();
        }
        elseif ( 'children' == reset($item_key) && isset($wp->query_vars['clients']) ) {
            wp_safe_redirect( get_permalink($page_id) . 'children/'  );
            exit();
        }
    }
}

// Step 6. FLush rewrite rules:
// Go to Settings > Permalinks and click on "Save Changes".
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

related: [WooCommerce My Account custom endpoint menu item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66716461/woocommerce-my-account-custom-endpoint-menu-item/66717141#66717141)