# WordPress AJAX request keep saying "The requested URL was not found on this server."

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have added a custom link in WooCommerce Menu using this thread [Add custom my account menu item based on user role in WooCommerce 3+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67195873/add-custom-my-account-menu-item-based-on-user-role-in-woocommerce-3) and Its working fine as per my expectations.

Now I have [select2](https://select2.org/) library and in my new custom page http://localhost/wordpress/my-account/clients/ I have added a dropdown with having the ability to select multiple.

And below is my code through which I am detecting if the user deletes an item from the dropdown and then I am firing the below event.

```
jQuery('.clientchildren').on('select2:unselect', function (evt) {  
  
  var userId = evt.params.data.id;     
  
  jQuery.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',  
              dataType: 'json',
              delay: 250, // delay in ms while typing when to perform a AJAX search
              data : {
                        action : 'remove_client_children_user_id',
                        userId : userId,                        
              },                       
              success: function(data)
              {  
                var data = JSON.parse(data);      
                toastr["success"]("Removed Successfully." );          
                
              }
            });

});
```

And In my **functions.php** file I have put the below code.

**functions.php**

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_remove_client_children_user_id', 'remove_client_children_user_id' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_remove_client_children_user_id', 'remove_client_children_user_id' );

function remove_client_children_user_id() {
    

    echo json_encode(array('status'=>1),true);
    exit;
}
```

But it never goes inside and it keeps saying

> The requested URL was not found on this server.

[image]

[image]

I even tried to use ajax calls by changing `action` with some of my old existing functions like `wp_ajax_get_mindesk_var_clients` by changing the `action` to `get_mindesk_var_clients` but still, it never goes inside to that as well.

Is it happening because I have created a new custom page and trying to achieve an ajax call to it?

Can someone guide me what should I do to make it work and where exactly it's having a problem calling ajax?

Thanks

Comment: where you put your js code?

Comment: in one of my custom.js file .. its executing fine ..

Comment: its going inside custom.js file .. I am able to pass request but its just not going an call ajax.

Comment: I have attached a screenshot ..

Comment: did you check what the ajax URL called?

Comment: I have attached on more screenshot how its called.

Comment: why its calling something like this `filename
 /wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` If I put static `url: 'http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',` then its working but i put only `url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',` then its not working ..

Comment: But for other functions `url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',` it seems to be working. So I am just wondering .. why this strang behaviour ?

Comment: How do you add custom.js? can you put that code in question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `wp_localize_script` to pass ajax URL to js. check the below code.

```
function theme_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_register_script( 'custom', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js.custom.js', array('jquery'), null, true );
    
    wp_localize_script( 'custom', 'custom_object',
        array( 
            'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
        )
    );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_scripts' );

jQuery('.clientchildren').on('select2:unselect', function (evt) {  
    var userId = evt.params.data.id;     
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: custom_object.ajaxurl,
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250, // delay in ms while typing when to perform a AJAX search
        data : {
            action : 'remove_client_children_user_id',
            userId : userId,                        
        },                       
        success: function(data){  
            var data = JSON.parse(data);      
            toastr["success"]("Removed Successfully." );          
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you Bhautik .. This is exactly what I wanted. I have used global variable for ajax url. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Bhautik Can you please help me on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67716577/wordpress-woocommerce-suibscription-remove-particular-item-from-multiple-variabl Thanks