# Remove particular variation from dropdown in WooCommerce frontend

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I am using [WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce/) and [WooCommerce Subscriptions](https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-subscriptions) and its working as per my expectations.

Now I am creating a variable subscription product having multiple attributes like this.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now I want to remove/hide particular item from dropdown hence I am trying to use below code / hook which I believe might help me to achieve.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_args', 'hide_variations_for_mindesk_users');

function hide_variations_for_mindesk_users( $args ){        
    
   print_r($args);

    return $args;    
}
```

Now my question is, how can I remove or hide particular variation product from dropdown? Do I need to remove from variation id or from somewhere?

---

For example:

Here I want to remove/hide 2nd variation from dropdown which has variation id **#4171** having "Monthly- Professional". This should work with single attribute as well.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [add-to-cart/variable.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/b19500728b4b292562afb65eb3a0c0f50d5859de/templates/single-product/add-to-cart/variable.php) template file, we find `foreach ( $attributes as $attribute_name => $options )`. However, the intention is to hide 1 attribute, so let's see where these are passed to the template file.

In [includes/wc-template-functions.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/8e45860732d9c4dd5cb1899c106c089717f19964/includes/wc-template-functions.php), we can see that the template file is called and an array is passed with some options. One of these options is `available_variations' => $get_variations ? $product->get_available_variations()`

The `get_available_variations()` function is then found in [includes/class-wc-product-variable.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/8e45860732d9c4dd5cb1899c106c089717f19964/includes/class-wc-product-variable.php) which in turn `$variation_ids = $this->get_children();` contains.

The `get_children()` function can then be found in [includes/class-wc-product-variable.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/8e45860732d9c4dd5cb1899c106c089717f19964/includes/class-wc-product-variable.php), which contains `apply_filters( 'woocommerce_get_children', $this->children, $this, false );`

And that filter hook can be used to remove one or more childIDs (variantions)

---

So you get:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_get_children( $children, $product, $false ) {
    // NOT backend
    if ( is_admin() ) return $children;

    // Variation ID
    $variation_id = 4171;
    
    // Delete by value: Searches the array for a given value and returns the first corresponding key if successful
    if ( ( $key = array_search( $variation_id, $children ) ) !== false ) {
        unset( $children[$key] );
    }

    return $children;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_children', 'filter_woocommerce_get_children', 10, 3 );
```

---

If you want to apply it for multiple variantion IDs, use:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_get_children( $children, $product, $false ) {
    // NOT backend
    if ( is_admin() ) return $children;

    // Variation IDs, multiple IDs can be entered, separated by a comma
    $variation_ids = array( 4171, 36, 38 );
    
    // Loop through variation IDs
    foreach ( $variation_ids as $variation_id ) {
        // Delete by value: Searches the array for a given value and returns the first corresponding key if successful
        if ( ( $key = array_search( $variation_id, $children ) ) !== false ) {
            unset( $children[$key] );
        }
    }

    return $children;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_children', 'filter_woocommerce_get_children', 10, 3 );
```

---

Used in this answer: [PHP array delete by value (not key)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7225113/11987538)

Comment: Thanks for your answer .. can you please elaborate, what is `$key` here ? How can I get and pass it to check in my `if` condition ?

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave An [array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) (`$children` in this case) consists of 1 or more a key(s) with corresponding value(s). Normally when you use [unset()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) on an array, you do this based on the key. However, because the `$variation_id` in the array `$children` is a value, not a key 
we use the if condition. If the `$variation_id` exists in the array, unset it. `$key` 
should not be modified in this answer, just the variation id if desired `$variation_id =` **4171** `;`